# Rails Engine Helper Files (Even with Work Around) Not Loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have title code that's getting repetitive, I decided to put it in an engine and load it in all my apps.

I'm having troubles loading helpers (even with the work around in engine.rb).

The host app is saying nomethod error, I don't think the helper files are loading. I can also render views from the engine fine, but still helpers won't load is there something I'm missing?

Code Block causing problems on main app.

```
<h1><%= yield(:phc_title) %></h1>
<span><%= yield(:phc_title_tagline) %></span>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ol>
```

/lib/phctitler/engine.rb

```
module Phctitler
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine

        # Required Dependencies
        require 'figaro'

        # Isolate Namespace for PHC Members
        isolate_namespace Phctitler

        # Testing Generator
        config.generators do |g|
            g.test_framework :rspec,
            fixtures: true,
            view_specs: false,
            helper_specs: false,
            routing_specs: false,
            controller_specs: true,
            request_specs: false
            g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: "spec/factories"
        end

        # Load Helper Files
        config.to_prepare do
            ApplicationController.helper(Phctitler::ApplicationHelper)
        end

        # Auto Mount Plugin
        initializer "phctitler", before: :load_config_initializers do |app|
            Rails.application.routes.append do
                mount Phctitler::Engine, at: "/"
            end
        end

    end
end
```

helpers/phctitler/application_helper.rb

```
module Phctitler
    module ApplicationHelper

    # Helper for Page Title
        def phc_title(phc_page_title)
            content_for :phc_title, phc_page_title.to_s
        end

        # Helper for Page Title Tag
        def phc_title_tagline(phc_page_title_tagline)
            content_for :phc_title_tagline, phc_page_title_tagline.to_s
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: Isn't it slightly overkill to use a full blown engine for one module?

Comment: Yeah a little, it's easier for me to roll out updates across many apps this way. I'm also going to consider adding keywords and seo description helpers to it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

I put the line below in the host application's controller.

```
   helper Phctitler::Engine.helpers
```